# Socket TCP in Nativescript

Tags: swift, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I create I wanted to create a plugin to create a tcp socket connection in Nativescript (there is not yet an online plugin that does this, only web sockets). [Following this guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods), I created a plugin and inserted the SwiftSocket library (in Swift) into the PodFile. Once imported and added to the project in NativeScript (Angular), I get an error:

`ERROR Error: Could not find module 'nativescript-socket-tcp"`.

How can I solve the problem? Can i use Swift library in Nativescript?

Comment: You will be able to use a Swift libraries only if the conditions mentioned here are met - https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#apis-written-in-swift

Comment: The actual error you have posted seems related to loading the module, do you have a public repo?

Comment: Hey OP, did you ever get around to launching your `nativescript-socket-tcp` ?